# Toast message shows each time i send sms

Tags: android, smsmanager

This is my code for sending SMS in ***ActivityOne***

```
        private void sendSMS(final String phoneNumber, final String message,final String userMsg)
        {
            String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
            //String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
            PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
            //PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
            //---when the SMS has been sent---
            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override   
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), userMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();

                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS not sent, Generic failure",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS not sent, No service",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS not sent,, Null PDU",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS not sent, Radio off",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, null);

        }
```

And i call it in Activity like this:

```
sendSMS(mobileNumber, "My Message", "SMS sent successfully");
```

I have same sendSMS method in next activity ***ActivityTwo*** but when i send sms from ***ActivityTwo*** then it show me toast of last activity ***ActivityOne*** each time.

Thanks.

Comment: are you unregistered `SMS_SENT` BroadcastReceiver  in `ActivtyOne` before moving to ActivityTwo ?

Comment: You called `registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){` at wrong place. You are registering a receiver in each call of sendSMS. That is not correct. You should register receiver at onResume method. And more IMPORTANT thing is that you must unregister this receiver at onPouse method

Comment: no i am not unregistering receiver in activity one. this can be the reason

Answer (score 1):

You can set your current context by adding one more parameter `this.context` and call toast like following:

```
 private void senSMS(final String phoneNumber, final String message,final String userMsg,Context context)
{
//do something
Toast.makeText(context, "SMS sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cancel the Toast if you had a reference to it but since it is created by a separate activity you can't access it.

create it like:

> Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);

Now you can cancel the toast with `toast.cancel()` see the documentation of the [Toast class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#cancel%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a problem where you are registering and unregistering your broadcast receiver.

> If registering a receiver in your Activity.onResume() implementation,
>   you should unregister it in Activity.onPause(). (You won't receive
>   intents when paused, and this will cut down on unnecessary system
>   overhead). Do not unregister in Activity.onSaveInstanceState(),
>   because this won't be called if the user moves back in the history
>   stack.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: How i can unregister?

Comment: Just call `Activity.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiverInstance)` during `Activity.onPause()`